# Adding google analytics to redmine

Tags: google-analytics, redmine

I am new to redmine & currently exploring all of its features. I want to add Google Analytics code to redmine. I searched in google & couldn't find anything useful. I found this article : http://dracoblue.net/dev/add-google-analytics-tracking-to-redmine/136/ where author mentioned to add the code to just base.rhtml. Since in newer versions, this file is base.html.erb, I tried adding code in it just before  tag. but that does not seem to work.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Google Analytics code to the end of `base.html.erb` should work fine - make sure you restart Apache/nginx/whatever you are hosting your Rails environment, so that the changes can be picked up.

Comment: It is not a good practice: use plugins for adding custom content. There is a plugin for GA: http://theadmin.org/articles/redmine-google-analytics-plugin/